# Gradle exec `error=2, No such file or directory` in Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

After updating to Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 (Mac OS), gradle exec plugin failed to work.

Here is an example of gradle task with exec:

```
task testExec(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'npm', '--version'
}
```

When run this task in Android Studio, get this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:241)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:218)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'npm'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/Users/pavel/AndroidStudioProjects/tempexec/app"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 8 more
```

But when run it from console - `./gradlew app:testExec`, everything is ok:

```
> Task :app:testExec
8.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the cause of the problem.

New Android Studio replaces `$PATH` variable for some reason. When launch `commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'echo $PATH'`, it prints: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. But `npm` is located in `/usr/local/bin/npm`.

The temporary solution for now is to add `/usr/local/bin/` to PATH like this:

```
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/; npm --version'
```

But, unfortunately, this solution kills cross-platform.